# Small Caps Bold ç in Lucida type 1 fonts

Tags: fonts, lucida

I'm using the Lucida type 1 fonts in a document written in portuguese.

When I typeset the word 'Definição' in small caps, I get a small caps
ç, but typesetting it in small caps bold, I get just a bold ç.

I suspect that that happens because the Lucida type 1 fonts doesn't have the ç
in small caps bold.

Is there anyway of getting a ç in small caps bold?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lucimatx}

\begin{document}
{\scshape Definição \textbf{Definição}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the font, which uses the normal lowercase ç instead of placing the cedilla under the small caps lowercase c.

Fixing it requires surgery in the virtual font file, I'm afraid.

Copy the file `hlhbc8t.vf` from the system to a working directory. Then run

```bash
vftovp hlhbc8t.vf > hlhbc8t.vpl
```

Now edit the created file `hlhbc8t.vpl` in the following way. Where you find

```
(CHARACTER O 347
   (CHARWD R 0.541)
   (CHARHT R 0.545)
   (CHARDP R 0.19)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 347)
      )
   )
```

it should become

```
(CHARACTER O 347
   (CHARWD R 0.621)
   (CHARHT R 0.545)
   (CHARDP R 0.19)
   (MAP
      (PUSH)
      (MOVERIGHT R 0.05)
      (SETCHAR O 270)
      (POP)
      (SETCHAR C c)
      )
   )
```

Now run `vptovf hlhbc8t.vpl`, which will overwrite the file `hlhbc8t.vf` and also create `hlhbc8t.tfm`.

If, in the same working directory, you run your example file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lucimatx}

\begin{document}
{\scshape Definição \textbf{Definição}}
\end{document}
```

you will get

[image]

How to always use these newly created files without further hassle? Run the following commands

```bash
> mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/vf/bhfix/lucida
> mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/tfm/bhfix/lucida
> mv hlhbc8t.vf $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/vf/bhfix/lucida
> mv hlhbc8t.tfm $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/tfm/bhfix/lucida
```

(where `>` represents the shell prompt).

I hope you're not on Windows. In case, somebody else might be able to help. I don't think that there's much hope to get fixed files from the developers.

Comment: Very nice answer. It solved my problem and I learned something about it.

Comment: I've just updated the Lucida distributions on TUG to fix the Type 1 font in question (lbdsc.pfb), and update the associated metric files. My little announcement on the lucida@tug,org mailing list is here: https://tug.org/pipermail/lucida/2020-December/000851.html

Comment: p.s. The same bug occurs in the OpenType font. The fix for that will have to wait for B&H. No ETA.

Comment: @KarlBerry Darn! We'll wait. :-)